# Force linebreak in VS05 SSRS textbox

Tags: reportingservices-2005

In a VS05 SSRS report I have a field coming back from the database that I concatenated together.

Ex:

```
SELECT Field1 + ' ' + Field2
```

I'm wanting to show this in a single textbox on the report but with a line break between the two fields.

I've tried:

```
Field1 + '\r\n' + Field2
```

but of course, no luck.

**What special characters can I use to force a line break in my cell?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add line breaks in SQL by concatenating `CHAR(10) + CHAR(13)` to your values.
However I'd advise you to do formatting in the report rather than the database.  In this case you would use the Visual Basic character `vbCrLf` in the texbox.

Comment: Great, but what if I want to add these chars in design mode, directly into the textbox control? Background: I want to paste some text from a Word document and physically add LR/CR into the textbox in design mode. Is there a ALT-something or some CTRL key combo to be able to do this? Thanks